# Dynamically addressing MATLAB modules without using eval/feval

Tags: matlab, dynamic

Consider a codebase with this file structure:

```
myScript.m (Script)
+modA/ 
    fn.m (Function)
+modB/ 
    fn.m (Function)
```

`myScript.m` must choose which of `modA.fn` or `modB.fn` to call at runtime using the outcome of a string `str_moduleName`.

Is there a way to avoid calling `feval([str_moduleName,'.fn'])` ?

Comment: If `+modA/` and `+modB/` are moved to be children of a common parent `+modParent/`  then the dynamic addressing `modParent.(str_moduleName).fn` works

Comment: That sounds like a good answer, please post it as such! The comment might disappear.

Comment: It has a significant drawback: with this approach all the preexisting code using the `modA` and `modB` namespaces would have to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I guess you could build a struct with function handles:

```matlab
S.modA = @modA.fn
S.modB = @modB.fn
```

Then you can call the function using the value of `str_moduleName` as follows:

```matlab
S.(str_moduleName)()
```

Comment: This indexing expression works, thanks. With this approach you have to maintain useless code to correctly populate `S`, but it is better than touching many files in a large codebase and maybe better than using `eval`.